# Automating a update function in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table called users in my laravel application database.

There is a column called `active_status` in the user's table

if the `active_status=0` then user is inactive and `active_status=1` user is active.

Also there is a column called, `user_score` in the users table. If the user score is less than 50 user's `active_status` should change to 0 and greater than 50 then user will remain as active user.

I have already written an update function to change this `active_status` but How can I automate the process, checking the user_score and updating the `active_status` accordingly?

Comment: Create event (executed, for example, each minute) which alters the status. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html

Comment: You can also use model event observers in Laravel. Create an observer for users table and it'll dispatch an event to update status.

Comment: Right way would be through mysql trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reffering something related to the laravel task scheduling.

Here is the official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling).

Comment: Using external scheduler is excess - MySQL has its own scheduler which is not delendent by Laravel.

Comment: True, but in this case laravel scheduler can be much more easier to use for the user

Comment: I doubt until you mean the user who do not want to read the documentation. Additionally - EVENT doesn't need in any support and works even Laravel is temporarily stopped/disabled. Additionally - MySQL scheduler doesn't need in process interconnection.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer using Event is this case - since it is fully Model Related:

You can set up your listener following the instructions here:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/events#registering-events-and-listeners

You can listen to the Model Update event as seen here:
https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#events

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you can use eloquent observers to do this.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#observers